# Regex Pattern to find

Tags: regex

I am trying to use regex to find specific characters

for example I have the followings string

```
var = "Data1<2,\<,\>,data2>1"
```

By using regex I want to find character `<` and `>` but the ones which does not has backslash (`\`) in front of it.

using my example it should only return 6th and 20th character

Thanks

Comment: And have you tried anything at all? And what language/IDE/whatever is this regex to be for?

Comment: Use a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match a character that isn't preceded by another character.

Comment: Without more details, we cannot help you much since regex is used to match text, and only some specific methods/functions can fetch you indices of the match positions. Moreover, if you have `Data\\<12>`, what should be the expected behavior (note that the backslash is escaped here, not `<`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/(?<!\\)(<|>)/`

This will fit your criteria of finding `<` or `>` that is not preceded by `\`.

Quick breakdown:

`(?<!\\)` is negative lookbehind for the character `\`. Note that we had to escape this character in order to match it literally. The negative lookbehind is just an assertion, it will not match anything.

`(<|>)` matches `<` or `>`